# DeadObjectException after service restart

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have activity in which is started service with `startService()` and in `onStart()` method binded to the same service. I'm sending some text using Messenger to service, then service open socket to the server in which this text is send to it, and server respond with some text (this working fine). The problem occurs when I'm trying to send response from service to activity using messenger. When application is started first time even that works fine, but after app is killed (so service restart) and I'm trying to send response from service to activity I get `DeadObjectException`. I commented line in service in which error occurse.

Here is my activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    TextView tvFromServer;
    EditText etSend;
    Button bSend, bStopSocket, bBound, bStopService;
    boolean mRun;
    Intent mIntent;

    /** Messenger for communicating with the service. */
    Messenger mService = null;
    /** Flag indicating whether we have called bind on the service. */
    boolean mBound;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        //SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        //        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        initialize();
        mIntent = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
        startService(mIntent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent iBind = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
        iBind.putExtra("messenger", new Messenger(mHandler));
        bindService(iBind, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
            mConnection = null;
            mHandler = null;
        }
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //Log.v("MapsActivity", (String) msg.obj );(String) msg.obj
            tvFromServer.setText(msg.getData().getString("text"));
        }
    };

    /**
     * Class for interacting with the main interface of the service.
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // established, giving us the object we can use to
            // interact with the service.  We are communicating with the
            // service using a Messenger, so here we get a client-side
            // representation of that from the raw IBinder object.
            mService = new Messenger(service);
            mBound = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
            mService = null;
            mBound = false;
        }
    };


    private void initialize(){
        tvFromServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_from_server);
        bStopSocket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_stop);
        mRun = false;
        bStopSocket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRun = false;
            }
        });

        etSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_send);
        bSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_send);
        bSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mBound) return;
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 1, etSend.getText().toString());
                try {
                    mService.send(msg);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        bBound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_bound);
        bBound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mBound) return;
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 1, "Hello from Activity");
                try {
                    mService.send(msg);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        bStopService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_stop_service);
        bStopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBound) {
                    unbindService(mConnection);
                    mBound = false;
                }
                stopService(mIntent);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

}
```

Service:

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
    public SocketService() {
    }

    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    public Messenger mMessenger, mUiMessenger;
    PrintWriter out;
    Socket mSocket;
    boolean mRun;
    Thread threa;


    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
            // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
            if(msg.what == 1){
                out.println((String) msg.obj);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("SocketService");
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
        mMessenger = new Messenger(new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper));
        mRun = false;

        threa = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                socketConnection();

            }
        });
        threa.start();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "binding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        mUiMessenger = (Messenger) extras.get("messenger");
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void socketConnection() {
        mRun = true;
        try{
            mSocket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxxx);
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream())), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));

            while(mRun){
                String s = in.readLine();
                Log.v("SocketServiceFromServer", s);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("text", s);
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 1);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                try {
                    mUiMessenger.send(msg); //DeadObjectException is thrown here after service is restarted
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mSocket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("SocketService ", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

logcat:

[image: ![logcat]

My question is, why this error is thrown? Looks like activity do not send new messenger object to service when binding to it after restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I found solution. I lost 4 hours on debugging code, search Internet and try millions of different approaches. Solution is very easy. Remove calling startService in your onCreate. Use only bindService and unbindService. Yes it is so simple...